# How to identify Valampuri Sangu (conch shell)?

Tags: rituals

The *Sangu*, or sacred conch shell is very auspicious in Hinduism and is used in many rituals. However, I have heard of a rare *Valampuri Sangu* which is supposedly even more sacred to use.

What is the *Valampuri Sangu* and how can I identify it?

Comment: What language is "Valampuri Sangu"? Are you talking about dakshiNavRta sankha?

Comment: @moonstar2001 `Valampuri` is Tamil. `Dakshinavarti Sangu` is the Sanskrit name for the same thing.

Comment: OK. It would help to at least give  English translations, if not Sanskrit, when using terms in the vernacular. Also, in Sanskrit it is Sankha not sangu. Thx.

Comment: I agree with @moonstar2001, you should give Sanskrit versions of terms rather than other languages.  (So for instance Vimana rather than Vimanam of Viman.)  See my answer here: http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/233/36 And things in languages other than English should be translated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**What is a Sangu?**

When performing *Aradhanam* for *Perumal*, it is important to use a *Sangu* or conch shell to bathe the *Vigraham*. *Sangu* are also commonly blown at the beginning and end of *Arti* in North Indian practice

The conch shell to be used comes from a particular species of sea snail known as *Turbinella Pyrum*, which can be found exclusively in the waters of the Indian Ocean. It is important that one uses the shell from the correct species, much as one should not use the leaves of another plant in place of *Tulasi*.

[image: Turbinella Pyrum]

**Valampuri Sangu**

You will notice in the picture above that if one were holding the *Sangu* with the crown facing upwards, the opening would appear on the right side of the shell. This is called a dextral shell. In very rare cases, approximately 1 in every 100,000, the shell will form with the opening on the left side, known as a sinistral shell. These extremely rare shells are known as *Valampuri Sangu*, and are considered very auspicious to use, as they are sacred to *Lakshmi*.

**False Valampuri**

Given how rare the *Valampuri Sangu* is, many scam artists will attempt to take advantage of buyers by hoarding *Sangu* to artificially inflate the price, or by falsely selling the shells of a different species as *Valampuri Sangu*. As a result, one must be especially careful when purchasing *Sangu* to ensure that one gets the correct species which can be used in worhsip.

[image: Lightning Whelk]

Shown above is the Lightning Whelk (*Busycon perversum*). This snail is native to Florida and the Caribbean islands. You will notice that it is sinistral, that is the opening is on the left of the shell. In fact, it is extremely rare to find a dextral Lightning Whelk shell.

Because of their naturally sinistral form, Lightning Whelk shells are often sold as *Valampuri Sangu* even though they are not the correct species and cannot be used in worship. It is easy to mistakenly purchase and use the Lightning Whelk shell thinking that it is a *Valampuri Sangu* so one must be very careful.

**Identifying a True Valampuri**

There are many features which distinguish the correct species *Turbinella Pyrum* from the Lightning Whelk. By paying attention to these differences, a careful observer can easily  identify whether a shell is a true *Valampuri Sangu* or a fake.

- Columellar plicae: *T. Pyrum* has 3 to 7 ridges along the inner column at the opening of the shell. The Whelk does not have these ridges and has a smooth inner column.
- Knobs: The Whelk has many knobs, or raised bumps, along the spiral at the crown of the shell. By contrast, *T. Pyrum* has smooth spirals.
- Crooked siphonal canal: The long end of the Whelk shell will usually (but not always) be slightly crooked. By contrast the long end of *T. Pyrum* tends to be fairly straight.

You can even see these differences illustrated in the pictures above. Of course, keep in mind that if it is difficult to tell, it is always better to use a dextral *Sangu* of the correct species than a sinistral Lightning Whelk.

**Sources**

- [Shankha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shankha)
- [Turbinella Pyrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbinella_pyrum)
- [Valampuri Sangu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dakshinavarti_Shankh)
- [Lightning Whelk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_whelk)

Comment: In addition to being sacred to Lakshmi, another reason why a sinistral conchshell is used is because that is the kind of conchshell that Vishnu holds.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Very true, although I have a hunch that Vishnu is usually depicted with that particular variant specifically because it is sacred to Lakshmi.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Also, after doing a few google image searches it looks like Vishnu is actually more commonly depicted with the dextral variety, so it could also just depend on the temple.

Comment: I think that's just because most people are more familiar with the the look of the dextral conchshell, so they automatically assume that's what Vishnu has.  But I think Vishnu's actual Panchajanya Shankha is a sinistral conchshell.  Let me try to find a reference for that.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous statement that the true Valampuri is a sinistral (whorls turning anti-clockwise fashion) variety of the species Turbinella pyrum L. It shows three to seven plaits or folds in the conch cavity (generally three to three and half). The best way is to do X Ray examination of the conch anatomy.  It is essential since many fake Valampuri shells  are floating in the market made by cut and paste method and then covering skilfully by the conch skin or greenish periostracum. True Valampuri is generally sold on the weight basis. It is charged in the range of Rs. 1500/- to Rs. 3500/- per gram.